# Jmeter-Docker giving org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:Response code 500. error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: docker, jmeter, dockerfile

Jmeter(Version 5.4) script running on Docker giving below error:

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.

```js
Build info: 
          version: '4.8.3', 
          revision: 'e5e76298c3'
System info: 
         os.name: 'Linux', 
         os.arch: 'amd64', 
         os.version: '5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2', 
         java.version: '1.8.0_362'
```

Error:

```
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*, --start-maximized, --headless=new, --disable-dev-shm-usage,--n...], extensions: []}, proxy: Proxy(system)}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*, --start-maximized, --headless=new, --disable-dev-shm-usage,--n...], extensions: []}, proxy: Proxy(system)}}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:148) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:106) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:165) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:183) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:158) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:101) ~[selenium-chromium-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:88) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:28) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.9.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:14) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.9.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:221) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.9.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:152) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.9.1.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:784) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:993) [jorphan.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:976) [jorphan.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:752) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:740) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:252) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [?:1.8.0_362]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we cannot help you without seeing your Dockerfile and JMeter .jmx script

The only recommendations I can provide so far are:

1. Run chrome in the Docker container with the same command-line flags and see what exactly is the error.
2. Make sure that Chrome and ChromeDriver versions match
3. It is not connected to your issue but worth doing: upgrade to [JMeter 5.6](https://lists.apache.org/thread/yw1zgbnc106frjc9lc4pgnbgo5mjss41) as it's [recommended to use the latest version of JMeter where possible](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling#use), moreover JMeter 5.4 is vulnerable to [Log4Shell](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4Shell)

Comment: I tried with  Jmeter 5.6 version too, getting same error.
However added capabilities too like "--disable-dev-shm-usage,--no-sandbox,--disable-gpu,--disable-extensions,disable-infobars,start-maximized" 
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*, --start-maximized, --headless=new, --disable-dev-shm-usage,--n...], extensions: []}, proxy: Proxy(system)}]}] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession~[selenium-remote-driver-4.9.1.jar:?]
but still an Error.